# Optional prefix for route in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, url-routing

I want to these URLs all match same controller:

```
/
/7
/articles
/articles/
/articles/7
```

Is it possible to add optional `prefix` to symfony's routing so the `article` prefix be optional?
How?

Comment: Deleted my answer since that doesn't work. Just try duplicating the routes instead.

Comment: I would reconsider this, using multiple completely different routes for one controller makes your app quite verbose. I would decide which one I choose. And maybe add redirects to the other one, if you need to be BC with your previous app or so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create 2 routeds pointing to the same controller:

```
acme_article_prefix:
    path: /articles/{id}
    requirements:
        id: \d+
    defaults: { id: 5 }

acme_article:
    path: /{id}
    requirements:
        id: \d+
    defaults: { id: 5 }
```

Another option is to make the prefix a placeholder too:

```
acme_article:
    path: /{_prefix}/{id}
    defaults: { _prefix: articles, id: 5 }
    requirements:
        id: \d+
        _prefix: articles
```

> for the framework, there is a patch for a long time to implement routes like `/(articles/){id}`, which will match the urks you set above.

Comment: the `/(articles/){id}` doesn't work; but using two routes works, Thank you

Comment: @4r1y4n it will work in the future :) (that's why I said "there is a patch", it's not implemented yet)